# Why does my Bootstrap and media query not responsive

Tags: bootstrap-4, media-queries, whitespace

I have these problems that when I convert my web to the mobile mode it zooms the entire page and leave white space in the right from top to bottom, how do I fix this, please.

Here's the link to my website https://juvielone.github.io/Juvie/

Image of white space in mobile mode:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the website? It's likely a missing or improper viewport meta tag, or an element exceeding the bounds of the body.

Comment: Here is the link  [link](https://juvielone.github.io/Juvie/) I've been using pesticide extension but still can't see the exceeding elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.prof-pic` image is set to a width of 21.875rem, or 350px (21.875*16px). Combined with the padding on `#about-me` and `.col-lg-6`, that element will exceed the bounds of many mobile device widths.

**Solution 1: Use a media query to set smaller dimensions on mobile devices.**

For example

```
.prof-pic {
    width: 13.875rem;
    height: 13.875rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    width: 21.875rem;
    height: 21.875rem;
}
```

**Solution 2: Make the image responsive**

Since you're using Bootstrap 4, you can use the helper class `.img-fluid` on `.prof-pic` to make images fluid (max-width: 100%). Since you want the image to have a consistent ratio, you would also need to crop your image to make it a square. This would also help with the image distortion.